# Derivation of Conditional Shannon Entropy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, probability

In the following question, I have found a few derivations for the conditional entropy, but the terms are in a different order.

> Show that Equation (5.11) comes from evaluating $$H(X|Y)=-\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Mp(x_j,y_k)\log_2(p(x_j|y_k)),$$ noting that only the probability in the logarithm is conditional.

> $$H(X|Y)=H(X,Y)-H(Y),\tag{5.11}$$

Now, I understand that Equation 5.11 reads "The Shannon Entropy of X given Y, is the difference between the Shannon Entropy of knowing both X and Y, and the Shannon Entropy of knowing just Y.
Is Equation 5.11 derived by using the evaluation sum in two cases of X and Y being completely correlated and completely uncorrelated?

Comment: You will find the answer in Cover&Thomas or perhaps even in the relevant Wikipedia article.